# Replace dataframe columns names with values of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

```
df1 = [ A     B
        X    y1
        XX   y2 ]

df2 = [ X    XX
        1    2
        2    3 ]
```

I want to replace the names of the df2 (X, XX) with the values of the same index in df1. So my result will be:

```
df2 = [ y1    y2
         1    2
         2    3 ]
```

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 2):

Make `df1` into a series of column B indexed by column A, and use that to rename the columns of `df2`.

```
renamed = df2.rename(columns=df1.set_index("A")["B"])
```